# Binding to a variable that may not exist

Tags: angular, primeng

What is the correct way of binding to `myVariable` when `myVariable` may not exist? (`myVariable` is from a service that may not be running)

`<input pInputText type="text" [size]="size" [value]="myVariable" style="cursor: pointer;">`

Wrapping the input component in a div, eg: `<div *ngIf="myVariable"></div>` will work (stop runtime errors) but the component would then be missing. Is there an elegant way I can still display the component, without errors, whether `myVariable` exists or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution 1: Using `||`

One way would be to use `||` to use an alternate value when the first value is undefined.

```html
<input pInputText type="text" [size]="size" [value]="myVariable || 'Default'" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

Here if the `myVariable` is undefined, string `Default` would be used.

#### Solution 2: using `*ngIf`'s `else`

Another rudimentary solution would be to have two versions of `input` tag by leveraging `*ngIf`'s `else` block. One with `myVariable` and one without.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="myVariable; else noVariable">
  <input pInputText type="text" [size]="size" [value]="myVariable" style="cursor: pointer;">
</ng-container>
<ng-template #noVariable>
  <input pInputText type="text" [size]="size" style="cursor: pointer;">
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below expression in ts file, if myVariable is present its value is displayed else empty will be displayed

```
 myVariable?myVariable:'';
```